# Unfortunately Application has stopped on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

Im new to android development so im following basic tutorials online. I followed a google map v2 android tutorial.The Android app crashes with the error, **"Unfortunately, my app has stopped working"**.I am using the most recent Android and Google Maps APIs (Android 4.2.2 and Google APIs 17).And I have done import the library project into project workspace[**File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace**].

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
        android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My Map API Key"/>       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

No Errors displayed in LogCat.So how can I find out why the app crashes?Does anybody have any idea about it?

Comment: there must be something wrong with Your logcat or You haven´t seen the output (is option "verbose", if not switch it). If Your app crash with this message, You must have an output in logcat.

Comment: Can you clarify a few points:  Are you using eclipse? which version? did you filter logcat? can you see logcat messages from other apps? how are you debuging? running on device or vm  / which version of android are you running on?

Comment: try to make your logcat level to 'Verbose' or put breakpoints in arbitrary points and debug it, it will guide you through

Comment: @Twisted yeah..am using Eclipse 4.2..I am using the most recent Android and Google Maps APIs (Android 4.2.2 and Google APIs 17).My app running on emulator android 4.2.2 API-17.

Comment: @OnurA. my logcat level is already set to 'Verbose'.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android-Manifest:

```
android:value="My Map API Key"
```

Here your own API-Key has to be written into the quotation marks. You can create it here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

And the Tutorial how to do that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

You should use the *debug certificate fingerprint*, not one for the release.

Comment: I have already done creating API key. hide my api key for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

This is a new requirement as of the updated google play services which is rev 13 i guess.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```